# How can you tell when a vacuum breaker needs to be replaced?

Tags: plumbing, shower

The one in the master bath just started "leaking" recently and now my daughter reports the same problem in her bath.  Is this just a part of their normal function or do they need to be replaced or possibly just adjusted?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's been abandoned

Comment: I'm  voting to close it due to lack of detail. Why would a bathroom have a vacuum breaker, which I normally associate with outdoor spigots? What's the model information? Why is "leaking" quoted? Is it not _actually_ leaking? Is it just _pretending_ to leak? Is this all just an elaborate _simulation_? What's _in_ the red pill, even?

Answer (score 0):

In order to answer the question with any assurance I would have to know what you mean by "leaking."  However I am willing to hazard the guess that the vacuum breaker is indeed operating as designed - that is to say it introduces air into the pipe/hose when a vacuum is induced.  This would cause the water to flow, and water flows in whichever direction is easiest.

Comment: True, but vacuum breakers are typically installed at a high point, so water flow would be easier somewhere else. Also, if it is leaking when under pressure, the seal or seat may be perished, corroded, or dirty. OTOH, some more elaborate backflow prevention devices may emit water as part of their normal operation.

Comment: @bcworkz your comment is a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

Before replacing, check to see if it needs cleaning.  If some debris is at the seal, it will leak.